# How to read only wav files in a directory using Python?

Tags: python, audio, numpy, wav

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
print files
for i in range(0,1):
w = read(files[i])
print w
```

I need to read only .wav files from python working directory. And store the each .wav files as a numpy array. This is my code. But in this code all files are read. I only read the wav files in the directory? How it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `glob` module and pass to it a pattern (like `*.wav` or whatever the files are named). It will return a list of files that match the criteria or the pattern.

```
import glob
from scipy.io.wavfile import read

wavs = []
for filename in glob.glob('*.wav'):
    print(filename)
    wavs.append(read(filename))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py", line 132, in read
    fsize = _read_riff_chunk(fid)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py", line 83, in _read_riff_chunk
    raise ValueError("Not a WAV file.")
ValueError: Not a WAV file.

Comment: @santh It seems that not all files in your directory that end with `.wav` are wav-files. How do you distinguish real wav files from other files if they have the same extension? By content?

Comment: Now the problem is solved. I need to save each wavefile array(ie,numpy aaray,that we get from the read command) as a separate .dat file.      g=len(wavs)
for i in range(0,g):
    h=wavs[i]
    g=h[1]   ,  np.savetxt('test.dat', g), but the file test.dat is overwritten in each for loop. So how can i save each wav file array as a separate .dat file?

Comment: @santh Since you already have a for loop counter `i`, use it to change the name of the file you save to: `np.savetxt('test-%d.dat' % i, g)`. This way you'll get `test-1.dat`, `test-2.dat`...

Comment: @Viktor.. Ok.. Now i am working on Windows.. Whether this glob commnad will work on linux/ubuntu?

Comment: @santh Yes it works on every platform (everything in the standard library is cross-platform if it's not explicitly noted differently in the docs). Just don't hardcode any backslashes, use `os.path.join`. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `glob`, then something like this will also work:

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.endswith(".wav")]
```