# How can I read many wavfiles in scipy?

Tags: python, scipy

I have a thousand of .wav files. I want to read 200 of them using from scipy.io import wavfile. They are named like this , voice1, voice2, voice3,...and so on. I want to read voice1-voice200 using scipy.

Which is the fastest way? Do I need to use a for loop?  How can I do that for loop?

Comment: What do you mean with "read", for what purpose? Usually it is better not to load an entire file into memory, but use  file handler and read and processes pieces of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'll need to use a for loop when you're doing the same thing over and over again.

If you want to get every .wav file in your directory, you should look at this answer:

[How to read only wav files in a directory using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895919/how-to-read-only-wav-files-in-a-directory-using-python)

That answer gives you a for loop to iterate through every file that ends in .wav; however, you don't want to just get every file that ends in .wav: you already know the names of the files, and you want to iterate through them

```
import glob
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
wavs = []
     for i in range(1,200):
         wavs.append(read('voice' + str(i) + '.wav'))
```

This block of code will iterate from voice1.wav to voice200.wav in the current directory, and then add the read .wav into the array wavs. If you wanted to print the elements in the array, you could do something like this:

```
for wav in wavs:
    print(wav)
```